# how to change custom dialog orientation without change activity orientation

Tags: android

i have a custom dialog and i want to show it in landscape mode but the activity that i am showing this dialog in it, is fixed in portrait mode.
how can i change the orientaion of the custom dialog in this activity?

here is my code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(wefwefwefewfsdac.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_pics);
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: Isn't this code working? I think that if you force your activity to be in portrait, you can't change the orientation of a single layout inside of this activity. You might want to start another activity, with a LANDSCAPE orientation, and show the dialog in that activity. Closing that dialog should finish() the activity as well

Comment: So if i do like that you said if user touch outside the dialog so the dialog would not close. am i right? @LucaNicoletti

Comment: You can achieve the "dialog won't close if I touch outside of it" using dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)